# How to make a coroutine private in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, coroutines

[image]
I am trying to make a coroutine private in Unity. I have tried declaring it as a private method, but it still seems to be accessible from other classes.

Here is an example of the code I am using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyPatrol : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1f;
    public float minX;
    public float maxX;
    public float waitingTime = 2f;
    private static IEnumerator PatrolToTarget;
    private GameObject _target;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       UpdateTarget();
       StartCoroutine(PatrolToTarget());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void UpdateTarget()
    {
        if (_target == null)  {
            _target = new GameObject("Target");
            _target.transform.position = new Vector2(minX, transform.position.y);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
            return;
        }

        if (_target.transform.position.x == minX) {
            _target.transform.position = new Vector2(maxX, transform.position.y);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);

        }

        else if (_target.transform.position.x == maxX) {
            _target.transform.position = new Vector2(minX, transform.position.y);
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
            }

        private void IEnumerator PatrolToTarget() {
        
            
            while(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, @this._target.transform.position) > 0.05f) 
            {
                    Vector2 direction = _target.transform.position - transform.position;
                    float xDirection = direction.x;

                    transform.Translate(direction.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
                    //importante
                    yield return null;
            }

                Debug.Log("Target reached");
                transform.position = new Vector2(_target.transform.position.x, transform.position.y);

                Debug.Log("Waiting for " + waitingTime + "seconds");
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(@this.waitingTime);

                Debug.Log("Wait enough, let´s update the target and move again");
                UpdateTarget();
                StartCoroutine(PatrolToTarget());
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you accidentally nested `PatrolToTarget` inside `UpdateTarget`. What happens if you un-nest this, and correct the method signature to `private IEnumerator PatrolToTarget ` (i.e. no `void`)?

Comment: I need more information, can you explain that to me?

Answer (score 3):

Where you put your code matters.

When you write code like this:

```cs
private void UpdateTarget() {
    // Update code here...
}
```

*All* the code between the opening `{` and closing `}` belongs to the `UpdateTarget` method.

So when you wedge another function inside it, like this:

```cs
private void UpdateTarget() {
    // Update code here...

    IEnumerator PatrolToTarget() {
        // Patrol code here...
    }
}
```

...then what you've done is define what's called a [Local Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) that belongs to `UpdateTarget`. Instead of adding a new member function to the class, the `PatrolToTarget` function is now visible *only* to code inside the `UpdateTarget` method. Code elsewhere in the class cannot see it.

This is obviously not what you want, because you're trying to call `PatrolToTarget()` from `Start`.

Your method signature is also invalid here:

```cs
private void IEnumerator PatrolToTarget()
```

- `void` and `IEnumerator` are both return types, but you're only allowed to have one.
- `private` is not a valid modifier for a local function, since *all* local functions are super-private to just the containing code block.

This last error is the one your compiler is complaining about. Because you've given it invalid code that cannot compile, it gives up, and doesn't mention the fact that `PatrolToTarget` is not visible from `Start`. Unity and your IDE will keep using the last successfully compiled version, which was probably one where this function was still public, and that's what's causing the illusion that it was somehow not possible to make it private.

So, remember, always fix all your compiler errors before trying to solve a bigger problem - they usually point you in the right direction, and one unsolved error can mask more pressing ones hiding behind it.

With that out of the way, here's how to make a coroutine private:

```cs
private void UpdateTarget() {
    // Update code here...
}
// Note that we've closed the } so we're outside UpdateTarget now.

private IEnumerator PatrolToTarget() {
    // Patrol code here.
}
```

There's no trick to it at all. We just write `private` in front of it like any other method. You just have to pay attention to where you're writing your code, and ensure that if you want to define a member function, you're writing it in the body of the containing class, not wedged inside another function.

Be sure to also delete `private static PatrolToTarget;` from the top of your class. This declares a variable with the same name as the function, so you'll have a collision if you leave it there. You never assign this variable anywhere, so it's just junk code that's not doing anything useful.